# How to install pear pecl package trader?

Tags: php, ubuntu, pear

I am trying to install PHP Extension trader using pecl install trader 
and it returned errors.

This is a ubuntu 16.04 server running PHP 5.6 this is my loaded php modules

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

```
root@traderlab:~# pecl install trader
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Downloader.php on line 593
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader.php on line 593
downloading trader-0.5.0.tgz ...
Starting to download trader-0.5.0.tgz (299,829 bytes)
............................................................done: 299,829 bytes


 > Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870
332 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
root@traderlab:~#
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Install `phpize`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Jonnix:

If you read the error messages, you will see that it says `sh: 1: phpize: not found`, meaning that phpize likely isn't installed. You should be able to install it using `apt install phpize`.

Comment: I followed the steps it started installing but at last the installation was failed 
root@traderlab:/var/www/html# pecl install trader
pecl/trader is already installed and is the same as the released version 0.5.0
install failed

Comment: Well, the installation failed because it is already installed. That's the way I read that message anyway. Try checking your loaded modules again to see if it worked. Also check if you just need to add it to a configuration file to load it.